# error "Text string muse be rendered within a text..." when Clear Text input

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

i have simple text input to enter phone:
**the problem**: whenever i delete **all** the characters from the text input its break and show me "text strings must be  rendered within a  component.

anyone guess why?

```
const PhoneEnter = ({ phoneNumber }) => {
const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);

return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : 
   "height"}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>המספר ששמור במערכת הינו:</Text>
        <TextInput
            defaultValue={state.phone}
            autoFocus={true}
            keyboardType="numeric"
            selectionColor="white"
            color="white"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={value => phoneNumber(value)}
        />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
 };
```

- note that if i delete the defaultValue={state.phone}
- when i delete the onChangeText prop is not crash. so the problem is there somehow

phone number function goes from parent component :

```
<PhoneEnter phoneNumber={value => setPhone(value)} />}
```

and there he have a state :

```
const [phone, setPhone] = useState(false);
```

Comment: Show us `phoneNumber` function.

Comment: i editted my post thank

Comment: And where is `phone` used?

Comment: ok i find the problem with the help of your questions.
i have this condition:
{massageType.key !== -1 && selectedHour && phone &&
that crash it..

Comment: So did you solve it?

Comment: yes i can take it from here... thank u.
if we are here... u can help me with regex for exactly phone number like this?
0549149822

Comment: 10 characters length string which contains only numbers leading zero?

Comment: Exactly.........